# move Cursor to next text Field by key listener in java

Tags: java, keylistener

I want to move Cursor to next text Field when presses Enter. To do that, I added a key listener to

[image]

upper textfield, but I don't know the codes that want to put inside the listener.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the action listener simply request focus for the next text box

```
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         YourNextTextBox.requestFocus();
    }
};

JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.addActionListener( action );
```